# Classification of an optimisation problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following minimisation problem
$$
\inf_x\left\{a^Tx : ||B^Tx-c||_2 \leq \rho, x\geq 0_{p}\right\}
$$
where $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$, $0_p$ is the $p\times 1$ vector of zeros.

Can this be classified as a linear optimization problem with conic constraints? If not, can you tell me the exact qualification of this problem?

Comment: there is no such thing as a "linear optimization problem with conic constraints", could you clarify what you are looking for? The easiest classification is a quadratic optimization problem.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking for a formal way to denote this problem. Quadratically constrained linear programming problem would be appropriate, for example?

Comment: 'programming' is outdated so you should call it a quadratically constrained linear optimization problem, although noone would bat an eye if you called it a quadratic optimization problem or a second-order cone optimization problem (SOCO is slightly more general than QO)

Comment: Thanks. May I ask you where does the "second-order cone" part come from? "Second-order" because the constraint contains $x^2$?

Comment: It comes from the second-order cone (also called the Lorentz cone or ice cream cone). I am sure the second power in the definition of the cone has something to do with its name, but you can have higher powers in a SOCO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem falls under the category of Second-Order Cone Programming (SOCP) problems, see, e.g., the [Mosek modeling cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html).
Such problems can be solved with a number of optimization solvers, e.g., CPLEX, Gurobi, Mosek, or ECOS.

The classification depends on the algebraic representation of your objective/constraints. There can exist several equivalent representations that fall under different classes.
For instance, if you write the constraint $\| Bx - c\|_{2} \leq \rho$ as $(Bx - c)^{T}(Bx - c) \leq \rho^{2}$, then you get a *quadratically-constrained* programming (QCP) problem.